# How to set up Git bare HTTP-available repository on IIS

Tags: git, version-control, iis-7, dvcs

My server already runs IIS on TCP ports 80 and 443. I want to make a centralized "push/pull" Git repository available to all my team members over the Internet.

So I should use HTTP or HTTPS.

But I cannot use Apache because of IIS already hooking up listening sockets on ports 80 and 443! Is there any way to publish a Git repository over *IIS*? Does Git use WebDAV?

**Update.** It seems that Git HTTP installation is read-only. That's sad. I intended to keep the stable branch on a build server and redeploy using a hook on push. Does anyone see a workaround besides using SVN for that branch?

Comment: Of the three suggestions in the selected answer, what solution did you end up using? How has it worked out for you? I'm in a similar situation now and would love a recommendation.

Comment: @Andy We've used OpenSSH/msysgit on Windows to setup standard SSH repository. Now (at different company) we use small Debian VM with SSH/gitosis. However it's a bit harder to backup.

Comment: My project [WebGit.NET](https://github.com/otac0n/WebGitNet) has been around for a while, but we just released version 2.0 Current Features: - Push/Pull over HTTP/HTTPS - Commit Log - Graph view - Plugin infrastructure - Impact plugin (shows users and their contribution impact) - Syntax highlighting via SHJS - Raw file downloads - Image viewer for images in the repository Things we are planning on supporting in the future: - Issue tracker plugin - Whatever *you* want! (Add a feature request on GitHub, and we'll see what we can do!)

Comment: @Artem Tikhomirov your really rescued me by `Update. Seems that git HTTP installation is read-only one.`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**Bonobo Git Server**

https://bonobogitserver.com/

---

**GitAspx** - By Jeremy Skinner

https://github.com/JeremySkinner/git-dot-aspx/

https://github.com/JeremySkinner/git-dot-aspx/downloads

*Install Instructions*

https://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2010/10/19/gitaspx-0-3-available/

---

**Git Web**

https://gitweb.codeplex.com/

---

**WebGitNET**

https://github.com/otac0n/WebGitNet

---

***Alternatively ...*** (non-IIS, but highly recommend, free and open-source)

**Gitea** (fork of Gogs): https://gitea.io

**Gogs**: https://gogs.io

**SCM Manager** allows you to easily set up revision control endpoints for **Git**, **Hg**, and **SVN** under the same hosting process. HTTP/HTTPS is supported along with built-in user authentication.

https://www.scm-manager.org
https://bitbucket.org/sdorra/scm-manager/

Answer (score 6):

Git supposedly supports webdav, and should work with any webdav server.  However, it's really slow compared to the native git protocols.

http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/setup-git-server-over-http.txt

Comment: This documentation is for use with Apache and not IIS.

Answer (score 3):

Today Git ain't too bad on Windows these days.

And if you want to use SVN on port 443 and/or 80 when IIS is already using it, try the tool at http://gstoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SvnReverseProxy&ProjectName=gstoolkit which is a reverse proxy that allows IIS to transparently pass thru SVN to a back-end VisualSVN server (running on the same machine on port 8080).

I'm still trying to get WebDAV and Git working on Windows though. (either by Apache's or IIS's WebDAV).

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to setup Git with MSysGit without cygwin.
http://java2cs2.blogspot.com/2010/03/setup-git-server-on-windows-machine.html

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to run a Git [Smart HTTP](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Smart-HTTP) server (supporting both push and pull from remote clients over HTTP) on Windows without any extra dependencies besides IIS and Git.

The [portable version of Git](https://git-scm.com/download/win) includes an executable called `git-http-backend.exe` which implements the Smart HTTP protocol which is designed to run through [CGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) on any web server.

You can secure the Git server using HTTP Basic Authentication and HTTPS. You can use Windows accounts and file/folder permissions to control access rights to individual repositories.

Full detailed instructions are here: [How to run a Git server on Windows with IIS](https://smalltech.com.au/blog/how-to-run-a-git-server-on-windows-with-iis).

Comment: I tried to follow the instructions on the above link but I could not find the "git-http-backend.exe" file mentioned. It was not available with my installed git. Do you know where I can get it?

Comment: git-http-backend.exe is available with the portable version of Git, available here under "Portable": https://git-scm.com/download/win.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instruction that uses SCM-Manager and IIS: [Hosting Git, SVN and Hg (Mercurial) repositories on Windows with IIS](http://www.helicontech.com/articles/hosting-git-svn-and-hg-mercurial-repositories-on-windows-with-iis/)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu is the engine behind deployments on Azure. This might help for anybody still asking this question...