# Using GIT Smart HTTP via IIS

Tags: windows, git, iis, smart-http

I recently read Scott Chacon's post "[Smart HTTP Transport](http://progit.org/2010/03/04/smart-http.html)", and I was hoping that it might have become possible via IIS (windows 7) since that post was written. I haven't been able to find anything showing how it can be done, and Apache is not an option in my IIS 7 based environment. So, I'm at a loss (git daemon was foiled for me by a combination of AVG anti-virus and AD).

I want to provide LDAP authenticated read/write access for selected users. So [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51619/how-to-setup-git-bare-http-available-repository-on-iis-machine) question seems not to be relevant.

Do you know of a way to provide access to GIT via IIS?

Comment: My project [WebGit.NET](https://github.com/otac0n/WebGitNet) has been around for a while, but we just released version 2.0 Current Features: - Push/Pull over HTTP/HTTPS - Commit Log - Graph view - Plugin infrastructure - Impact plugin (shows users and their contribution impact) - Syntax highlighting via SHJS - Raw file downloads - Image viewer for images in the repository Things we are planning on supporting in the future: - Issue tracker plugin - Whatever *you* want! (Add a feature request on GitHub, and we'll see what we can do!)

Comment: Thanks John, I'm not at that company any more, so for now it's someone else's problem. However I will take a look, because it may be an issue sometime in the future.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just created [a project](http://gitweb.codeplex.com). It has an ASP.NET HttpHandler that follows what Grack does. Welcome to try it out.

Comment: thanks, yysun. I will! PS. Why codeplex, and not github? :)))

Comment: not so nicely across the network: "did you run git update-server-info on the server?"

Comment: Sadly I'm getting Http 400 errors on latest release. GitAspx is working find though

Answer (score 8):

**GitAspx** - By Jeremy Skinner

http://github.com/JeremySkinner/git-dot-aspx/downloads

*Install Instructions*

http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2010/10/19/gitaspx-0-3-available/

---

**Git Web**

http://gitweb.codeplex.com/

---

**Bonobo Git Server**

http://www.chodounsky.net/bonobo-git-server/

---

**WebGitNET**

https://github.com/otac0n/WebGitNet

---

***Alternatively ...*** (non-IIS)

**Gitea** (fork of Gogs): https://gitea.io

**Gogs**: https://gogs.io

**SCM Manager** allows you to easily setup Git, Hg, and SVN servers over HTTP/HTTPS under a separate Java process and complete with built in authentication.

http://www.scm-manager.org/
https://bitbucket.org/sdorra/scm-manager/

Comment: Thanks Brian. Is this new? I didn't see references to it at the time I posted this Q.

Comment: any ideas on how to add a password to GitAspx? Right now anyone can push/ pull/ etc

Comment: You can try Git Candy, A Git platform based on ASP.NET MVC. Source on:http://github.com/Aimeast/GitCandy, Demo on: http://git.53wb.com/

Comment: windows.. it is absurd that people even use it as a server in enterprise environments.. oh well... i have the same problem. working at a bank which doesn't understand technology..

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do this with the Rack support in IronRuby (http://github.com/jschementi/ironruby/tree/master/Merlin/Main/Hosts/IronRuby.Rack) and the Git http server rack app (http://github.com/schacon/grack).  You need at least Git 1.6.6, possibly 1.7.0 for this to work - I'm not sure that it will, but it might.  If you're running any Java app servers, you can compile Grack into a WAR, too, if that's an option.

Comment: I'm not sure whether that's a 'yes' or a 'no', but it certainly sounds like an 'it's hard'. Thanks Scott.