# setup remote Git server for testing EGit

Tags: windows, git, egit

I need to setup a Git server on windows 7 with IIS to test my EGit with eclipse. Eventually it would be use to checkout and checkin from a remote server. But I would like to test the remote checkout and checkin for EGit using a local server as of now. I have tested it to work with Github (only https not SSH, SSH seemed to have a problem). But I would like to host my own git remote server for EGit. Please let me know as to how to go about it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the "[Git Web Access](http://gitweb.codeplex.com/)" project:

> For those who have interests in a Smart-HTTP Git server on IIS, the project provides an ASP.NET `HttpHandler` that let you run Smart HTTP Git on IIS.
>   It is inspired by Grack, a Ruby Rack based application for Smart HTTP Git and [`git_http_backend.py`](https://github.com/dvdotsenko/git_http_backend.py), a python implementation of Smart HTTP Git.

You also can try out the "[Bonobo-Git-Server](https://github.com/jakubgarfield/Bonobo-Git-Server)" project, through its [main project page](http://www.chodounsky.net/bonobo-git-server/).

> Bonobo Git Server for Windows is a web application you can install on your IIS and easily manage and connect to your git repositories.

You will find other alternatives (sometime older) in "[How to setup GIT bare HTTP-available repository on IIS-machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51619/how-to-setup-git-bare-http-available-repository-on-iis-machine)".

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback. I set up msysgit as specified in http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/296398/Step-by-Step-Setup-Git-Server-on-Windows-with-CopS and got it running on loclhost. Then on Amazon on a linux instance, i used gitolite (which uses only ssh mode). I am sure if I would have tried out your solution, it would work.

Comment: @suchitranair Excellent. Minor point. Gitolite doesn't "only" uses ssh mode. It is an authorization layer which will rely *primarily* on ssh for the authentication, but can be linked other mechanisms like an http server / LDAP authentication. See "authentication versus authorisation": http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/auth.html

Comment: Thank you so much. I was wondering how to get it done in case I needed to have http authentication. I'll surely take a look at it.

Comment: @suchitranair see my `httpd.conf` example, where I call gitolite after an LDAP authentication. https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/apache/env.conf.tpl#L95-L108

Comment: Thanks a lot :). I will be taking this up after sometime. I am sure I will have a lot of queries then and now I know where to return for answers :)