# Is there a guide for setting up GitHub as a versioning environment for .Net sites over the internet?

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

My company is looking in to versioning systems to work over the internet, and right now it looks like Git, possibly using GitHub would be a good option.

We have programmers who work from inside the office in our LAN but we also have programmers who work remotely and all would need access. All of our coding is done in Visual Studio (2010,2012) so a solution that works with it would be best.

Ideally, we would like to be able to clone our repositories on our local system and have our files automatically updated on our development server, which runs .Net web applications on IIS.

GitHub, with private repositories, seems like a good option for us to access our files from inside or outside our network, but I can't find a way for us to get GitHub to update the development server when changes are committed.

GitHub isn't really a necessary part of the equation - it just seemed like a good way to manage the task over the internet.

Can anyone point me to a good guide for accomplishing what we need?

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help

[How to setup GIT bare HTTP-available repository on IIS-machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51619/how-to-setup-git-bare-http-available-repository-on-iis-machine)

or  [Hosting a Git server under IIS7 on Windows](http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2010/06/25/hosting-a-git-server-under-iis7-on-windows/)