# How should I set up my repositories on Windows without SSH?

Tags: windows, git

I have git running on Windows without a problem, but I'm ready to set up my live server, and I have the following issue. I don't have SSH or a work-around set up. Therefore, I can't simply create a bare repository on the server, push to it, and call it a day. Without SSH, there's no connecting to that directory (as far as I know).

Assuming that I will/cannot set up SSH, how would I go about configuring my repositories? I don't want to have to RDP onto my server to do a pull every time I have changes to commit.

Any suggestions or comments are welcome. Please note that I'm not looking to set up SSH. I'm looking for a way to configure my setup WITHOUT SSH. Thanks!

EDIT: my question is different from the other question because I am not looking for a way to set up SSH on windows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git for beginners: The definitive practical guide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide)

Comment: i don't see how. all of those links referring to windows include some sort of work around for ssh, as in how to get ssh on windows. i don't want an ssh setup or work around.

Answer (score 0):

The "easiest" option on Windows is to put your `--bare` repository on a file share of some sort. Permissions controlled by Windows, etc. You can also [serve Git from IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4015421/54249).

That said, for all but the most trivial use cases I would recommend a "real" Git server product.